# Scrapy - Formatting Content and HTML attributes

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I'm doing a scrape of a site with Scrapy for import, but I'm having trouble with formatting of internal links.

Take the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="PageContent">
    <a href="files/documents/path1.pdf">Click me</a>
    <a href="files/documents/path2.pdf">Click me</a>
    <a href="files/documents/path3.pdf">Click me</a>
</div>
```

The XPath:

```
item["page_content"] = response.xpath("//div[@class='PageContent']".encode("ascii","ignore"))[0].extract().replace('\r','')
```

This works well.  I also check the response for any files, and download them too.  I've customised FilesPipeline so that it keeps its relative path and name, and doesn't turn it into a GUID

```
pdf_urls = nodes.xpath(u'//a[@href[contains(., ".pdf")]]/@href'.encode("utf-8")).extract()
```

This is also working well.

What I need to do is to modify `item["page_content"]` and prepend a string to the front of and of the HREF attributes, if the extension is a .PDF. I have tried this (and various versions):

```
for attr in response.xpath(u'//a[@href[contains(., ".pdf")]]/@href'):
    attr[href] = "/new/dir/in/front" + attr
```

To no success.  Also, if even if I've successfully modified this data how do I stop `items["page_content"]` from becoming a list with these new attributes?  My desired result is

```
items["page_content"] =     <div class="PageContent">
                                <a href="/new/dir/in/front/files/documents/path1.pdf">Click me</a>
                                <a href="/new/dir/in/front/files/documents/path2.pdf">Click me</a>
                                <a href="/new/dir/in/front/files/documents/path3.pdf">Click me</a>
                            </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I played around with this for a while, but I ended up using an XML/HTML parser to format my data.  It was much easier, much faster and gave much more control. Posting this answer up for anyone who might run into a similar problem.

A snippet of the code:

```
from lxml import html as HTML
from lxml import etree as ET

...

doc_pattern = ('//a[@href['
           ' contains(., ".pdf") or' 
           ' contains(., ".dot") or'
           ' contains(., ".rtf") or' 
           ' contains(., ".doc") or'
           ' contains(., ".xls") or' 
           ' contains(., ".docx") or'
           ' contains(., ".xlsx")'
           ']]')

def parse_page_html(pattern, 
                    response=response, 
                    HTML=HTML, 
                    ET=ET
                    ):

            parser  = ET.HTMLParser(remove_comments=True, remove_blank_text=True)
            content = response.xpath(pattern)[0].extract()
            content = content.encode("ascii","ignore")
            content = content.replace('\r','').replace('\n','').replace('\t','')
            body    = HTML.fromstring(content, parser=parser)

            for links in body.xpath(doc_pattern):
                links.attrib['href'] = remove_absolute_url( links.attrib['href'] )

...
content = ET.tostring(body)
return content
```

I've never done anything like this before (and had used Python for about 3 hours), but [lxml](http://lxml.de/) had me going in <45 minutes.  I ended up rewriting a lot of the script to leverage it and the result was fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to generate the items["page_content"] manually? Something like:

```
items['page_content'] = []
for attr in response.xpath(u'//a[@href[contains(., ".pdf")]]/@href'):
    items['page_content'].append("/new/dir/in/front" + attr)
```